# EF6 Code First Unable to Update Foreign Key on Object - referential integrity constraint

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a one to one relationship between Person and Place. If I try to change the PlaceId, or assign the Place property a new place I get errors. How are you supposed to change the related entities?

The below fails with: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

```
person.Place.PlaceId = placeId;
_db.Entry(person.Place).State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();
```

If I try updating with the below I get same error. Should I just use stored procedures for something like this? It took me several minutes to create a stored proc to do the update but several hours of messing with Entity Framework and I still can't get it to work.

```
person.Place = Place; //where Place is a valid object
```

Comment: The "it took me several hours" comment is just because you don't know how to do it.  Not because of anything wrong with EF.  If you didn't know how to do it in SQL, it might take you several hours to figure that out too.  In any event, it's hard to answer your question because you don't say exactly how you've defined your entities.  The way to do it would be different depending on different definitions.  When you say it's a 1:1, are you sure?  EF only supports 1:1 relationships with a shared primary key, and it doesn't look like that's the case here.

Comment: More than likely, you actually have a Many:1 that you only link one item to.  By the way, when you say "I tried xxx, but it didn't work", "didn't work" is vague and doesn't tell us anything... What happened when you did xxx?  Did you get an error?  Did it do nothing?  Did it sing the national anthem?

Comment: I think you misread part of it, I mentioned "If I try updating with the below I get same error." The below is "person.Place = Place;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a 1:1 relationship.

```
public class Person
{
  public int PlaceId {get; set;}
  [ForeignKey("PlaceId")]
  public Place Place {get; set;}
}
```

I finally got it to work by setting the property to null and then setting the FK property after that. Also, if I set the EntityState to modified before I set the FK value then I get the same error so it has to be done in this exact order. Which I am not a fan of because it is not intuitive and I could not find any documentation for how to do this.

```
 _db.People.Attach(person);
 _db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
person.Place = null;
person.PlaceId = placeId;
```